# How to get my background to work

Tags: css

I have a website where the background need to be stribes (got an image of the stripe) in my body css i set it as background-image and repeat it, so far so good:

```
    body
{
    font-family: Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    text-align: left;
    margin:0px;
    text-align:center;
    background-image:url(../Gfx/Design/bg.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#BGContainer
{
    margin:0px;
    background-image:url(../Gfx/Design/background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:101;
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="BgContainer">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Then i have this other image with a gradient in the top where the stibes fade into another color. This image should *overlay* the top of the background. This is what i tried to do in my code, but it isnt working. It only shows the tiling of the bg.png located within my body element. I never see the overlay. Anyone?

/Cheers

Comment: didnt touch it, Visual studio auto generated: 

<pre><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"></pre>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS is (supposed to be at least) case-sensitive - you have `#BGContainer` in the CSS but `BgContainer` in the HTML.

Comment: Assuming it's not just a typo here, this would be the problem.

Comment: Argh how stupid! thx a bunch that solved it. How terrible embarrassing.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add content inside your #BGContainer div, something like `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just include the gradient overlay into your stripes image?

Or am I misunderstanding your problem?

Comment: Then i cant tile it, the gradient should only appear in the top of the background. Im tiling a small img of the background. and then tiling a bigger image with the gradient on it on top of that (at least thats the plan)